# Почему при вводе команды /help телеграм бот вылетает?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу сразу предупредить, я только учусь и это мой первый код. Почему, когда я ввожу команду /help у меня вылетает бот и все перестает работать? Как мне сделать, чтобы эта команда работала безошибочно на протяжении всего теста.....

**Выдает следующее:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Анастасия
> Нартя\Desktop\smalltestmousebot-20220411T072449Z-001\testmouse_v6
> команда старт и реакция на другие слова.py", line 111, in 
> bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)   File "C:\Users\Анастасия Нартя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init*_.py",
> line 658, in polling
> self._*threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)   File "C:\Users\Анастасия
> Нартя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init**.py",
> line 720, in _*threaded_polling
> raise e   File "C:\Users\Анастасия Нартя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init**.py",
> line 680, in __threaded_polling
> self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()   File "C:\Users\Анастасия Нартя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
> line 135, in raise_exceptions
> raise self.exception_info   File "C:\Users\Анастасия Нартя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
> line 87, in run
> task(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\Users\Анастасия Нартя\Desktop\smalltestmousebot-20220411T072449Z-001\testmouse_v6
> команда старт и реакция на другие слова.py", line 69, in get_ind2
> itog += int(message.text) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/help'

````
    from telebot import types
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
    
    itog = 0;
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
    def welcome_help(message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"""<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, вот тебе моя подсказка:
        
    <b>Субъектная оптимизация.</b> 
    
    <b>Иерархическая оптимизация.</b> 
    
    <b>Функциональная оптимизация.</b> 
    
    <b>Информационная автономность процессов.</b> 
    
    <b>Автоматизация процессов.</b> 
    
    <b>Документация процессов.</b> 
        
        """, parse_mode= "HTML")
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Если моя подсказка помогла тебе, то в ответ можешь написать мне <i>"Спасибо".</i>', parse_mode= "HTML");
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def welcome_start(message):
        if message.text == '/start':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}!</b>', parse_mode= "HTML")
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='Да')
            keyboard.add(key_yes)
            key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='Нет')
            keyboard.add(key_no)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ты хочешь посчитать ИС выполненной задачи?', reply_markup=keyboard)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши "/start"!', parse_mode= "HTML")
    
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def messay(message):
        if message.text == 'Спасибо':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Рад помочь! Забудешь - пиши! :)')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ничего не понимаю! Напиши мне "/start" или "/help".')
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def iq_callback(call):
        if call.data == 'Да':
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id);
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"""Не забудь, что ответом является цифра :
        0 - не соответствует требованиям;
        1 - частично соответсвует;
        2 - полностью не соответствует.""");
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Субъектная оптимизация');
            bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, get_ind1);
        else:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ну ладно, заходи позже :(')
    
    def get_ind1(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 1
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Иерархическая оптимизация');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind2);
        
    def get_ind2(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 2
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Функциональная оптимизация');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind3);
    
    def get_ind3(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 3
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Информационная автономность процессов');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind4);
    
    def get_ind4(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 4
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Централизация информации');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind5);
    
    def get_ind5(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 5
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Автоматизация процессов');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind6);
    
    def get_ind6(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 6
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Документация процессов');
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_ind7);
    
    def get_ind7(message): #получаем ответ на вопрос 7
        global itog;
        itog += int(message.text);
        proc = round(itog*100/14);
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Задача оценивается в ' + str(itog) + ' баллов и ИС равен ' + str(proc) + ' %.');
        itog = 0;
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Продолжить', callback_data='Да')
        keyboard.add(key_yes)
        key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Закончить', callback_data='Нет')
        keyboard.add(key_no)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Всё? Или считать ещё раз?', reply_markup=keyboard)
    
    #Запускаем бота
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)```
````

Comment: Приведите лог падения.

Comment: Отредактировала вопрос

Comment: У Вас названия исходников python по русски написаны. Это может вызывать некоторые сложности у "профильных библиотек".

Comment: Изменила названия и проблема осталась..

Comment: Ну падает оно падает на `itog += int(message.text);`, а вот как сделать, чтобы при вводе `/help` всегда обращалось к обработчику `welcome_help`, а не к обработчику текущего шага диалога, это я не знаю, может кто-то подскажет.

Comment: Вообще в трейсбеке он жалуется на строку 69, где у Вас вместо числового значения в тексте какие то буквы скорее всего.  int(message.text)  - не срабатывает.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за помощь.